# awaken server coroutine from another process

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, coroutine

## server coroutine and task_loop coroutine in same process

I want to create a program, which contain a server receiving message from other process through socket or unix-socket , this program also contain a main loop to keep donig tasks.

I am thinking about the two implements:

### one is

1.a thread for the server
  2.a thread for the main loop
  3.communication between server and main task loop by queue

### two is

1.a coroutine for the server
  2.a coroutine for the main loop

the first would be more complicated because to coordinate threads in case of deadlock
  the second one , the server would be fail to receive message if main loop are keep running . if there any possibility let the server coroutine run when there is message through the socket?